# Apt-get version (build) sepecification

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Could you explain me what does that "+build-ubuntu" part means?

```
sudo apt-get install firefox=45.0.2+build1-0
sudo apt-get install firefox=28.0+build2-0ubuntu2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has a couple of patches to make firefox run flawlessly on its environment and play nicely together with its versions of libraries (i.e. libc). Theese patches are not part of firefox, but handled by the ubuntu maintainers. So in order to keep track of the level of theese patches, ubuntu adds this string to the original upstream version from mozilla for firefox.

Ubuntu maintainers can increment their part of the version by changing the suffix string +build2-0ubuntu2 to +build2-ubuntu3. At the same time upstream firefox can increment the main part of the version - and the new version will always be bigger, independent from the ubuntu patch version.

Also this might be used to add security patches in new firefox versions into old versions of firefox (without updating the whole firefox version). This is due to the nature of ubuntu to not update versions of packages within a release (i.e. ubuntu 16.04. sticks with the version of all packages when it was released in april 2016).